# firebase importing just the required packages

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, angularfire

I am using firebase within my Angular 6 application and when I use imports like the following,

```
import { auth, User } from 'firebase';
```

I get this warning in the browser console:

```
It looks like you're using the development build of the Firebase JS SDK.
When deploying Firebase apps to production, it is advisable to only import
the individual SDK components you intend to use.

For the module builds, these are available in the following manner
(replace <PACKAGE> with the name of a component - i.e. auth, database, etc):

CommonJS Modules:
const firebase = require('firebase/app');
require('firebase/<PACKAGE>');

ES Modules:
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/<PACKAGE>';
```

Whenever I switch the imports to something like `import * as auth from 'firebase/auth'`:

- I get a different error: `export 'GoogleAuthProvider' (imported as 'auth') was not found in 'firebase/auth'` (because I am also using `GoogleAuthProvider`)
- the `auth` variable doesn't have it's definition anymore and I can't CTRL-CLICK and see what is going on.

Comment: I've just tried `import * as auth from 'firebase/auth';` and no errors appear in the console. As you state, `import { auth, User } from 'firebase';` does show warnings in the console.

Comment: I updated the question. I get the error, as it cannot find the `GoogleAuthProvider` anymore, but the package I thought is meant to be the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to **danfri86**'s comment to this GitHub issue - https://github.com/firebase/angularfire/issues/968 - you should do the following:

```js
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/auth'; // This line is important

export const googleProvider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
```

This is in fact what the warning says to do:

```
ES Modules:
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/<PACKAGE>';
```

I've just tested it and it doesn't throw any errors.